# Function to split the string based on placeholder in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

If I have data in the following format in a `varchar` column:

Length and number of the string/number is not fixed (we can have data some thing like this as well : "t#1#newlink#22222#")

```
Id    string
1     "Test#123# new#456# #678#"
```

Output should be:

```
Id string 
----------
1  123
1  456
1  678
```

If its possible to split the string with out place holder also fine

My end result should be numbers in new rows.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: The real issue here is that you are storing multiple values in a single tuple. this violates 1NF and causes untold amounts of anguish. Don't do this to yourself. Since you are already in this unenviable position you are going to have to split this into reasonable values. Here are some great examples of this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: use `Replace()` to remove all non-numeric values... then use a string split function. There are hundreds of posts on this. [Here is a good on](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Comment: @DavidG:sql 2012

Comment: @Vivek check with your data

Answer (score 1):

using Split and XML we can achieve

```
Select * from  (

    select Id,split.xmlTable.value('.', 'varchar(255)') as String 
    from (

       select ID,cast(('<w>' + replace(String , '#', '</w><w>') + '</w>') as xml) as xmlValue
         from @T

    ) as xmlTable
    cross apply xmlValue.nodes ('/w') as split(xmlTable))T
    WHERE String  like '%[0-9]%'
```